# Mysql select parent and children from same table using a resolve table for parent child relation

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, parent-child, resolve

I have two  tables: Persons and Relations.
Some of the persons are parents of children also contained in Persons.
Using relationships as resolving the parent children relations with childrenID, parentID in a row

I want to select the names and other information from table persons of the parent and the children grouped toghether

Table: persons

Columns:
ID  int(11) AI PK ,
name    varchar(45),
surname varchar(45),
art varchar(45),
etc

Table: Relations
Columns:
ID  int(11) AI PK
pid1    int(11) (child)
pid2    int(11) (parent)
etc

I want to select the parent name and children name sorted together as "Family"

```
SELECT b.pid1,b.pid2, p.surname,p.name 
FROM persons p
left join  relations b  ON  p.ID=b.pid1
left join  relations b1 ON  p.ID=b1.pid2
WHERE p.ID=b.pid1 or  p.ID=b1.pid1  
order by b.pid2;
```

this retrive what i want but i can't get it sorted like this

1 row=> parentname, parentid, ....

2 row=> childname, childid, ....

3row=> childname, childid, ...

and so on

then the next family

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Start by getting rid of the Relation table -- Instead, have pid1 and pid2 columns in the Person table.  Then do "self joins".

Comment: It is not clear what your exampmle is an example of. Please explain clearly how you want it sorted. Please read & act on [mcve]. Note that you can sort a table on some fields but then not return some of them.